# Server generating env.json file in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

After running the Spring Boot Application, I can access a file on the server using the below link:

http://localhost:8080/myweb/env.json

This file not contains only the server-related data but also the application-related data. Application-related data has all the properties defined in the application.properties file. This is a security vulnerability.

```
{
  "profiles": [],
  "server.ports": {
    "local.server.port": 8080
  },
  "servletContextInitParams": {},
  "systemProperties": {},
  "systemEnvironment": {},
  "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]": {}
}
```

How this file is getting generated and how can we restrict it from accessing publically?

Comment: Are you using Spring devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Spring Boot Actuator

```
management.endpoint.env.enabled=false
```

will disable this endpoint

if it does not work try

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env
```

or you can disable all of them with this config

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
```

you can read more about it here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html

Comment: Actually, I'm using an older version of Spring Boot, so below property worked for me:
endpoints.env.enabled=false.
Thanks a lot, Andreas. Issue Resolved.